# Infer from subclass in Pylint

Tags: python, pylint, linter, astroid

I'm calling a method (assignment) which is present in the subclass, but pylint gives a `no-member` error as the called method is not defined in the base class.

Pylint uses `infer()` defined in NodeNG class (in astroid) for making these kinds of inferences. Is there a way to tweak the `infer()` method so that it considers the methods defined in the subclass as well?

Comment: It sounds like Pylint doesn't know that the object you're working with is an instance of that subclass.

Comment: add some code to see problem